# Jetpack Compose + Firebase Crash java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTableKt.groupSize(SlotTable.kt:2558)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on an application using firbase firestore realtime database.
The application once the user logs in for the first time will check if the user has a username. If not, it will display a popup to allow user name to change. User can also change the username via the drawer menu, which will also display the same popup.

This what my viewmodel looks like:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    private val _isLoggedIn = MutableLiveData(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser != null)
    val profile = UserProfile(_user.uid)

    var isLoaded: LiveData<Boolean> = profile.isLoaded
    var isLoggedIn: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoggedIn

    init {
        getInstance().addAuthStateListener() {
            _isLoggedIn.value = it.currentUser != null
        }
    }

    fun updateUsername(username: String) {
        profile.updateUsername(username)
    }

    fun logOut(){
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
    }

}
```

My Profile class looks like this:

```
class UserProfile(private val userId: String) {

    private val _isLoaded = MutableLiveData(false)
    private val _username = MutableLiveData("")

    var isLoaded: LiveData<Boolean> = _isLoaded
    var username: LiveData<String> = _username

    init {
        if (userId != "") {
            Firebase.firestore.collection("Users").document(userId)
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                    if (e != null)
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    if (snapshot != null) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            snapshot.getString("username")?.let { setUsername(it) }
                            if (_isLoaded.value == false)
                                _isLoaded.value = true
                        } else {
                            val data = hashMapOf("username" to "")
                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document("")
                                .set(data)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    private fun setUsername(newUsername: String) {
        _username.value = newUsername
    }

    fun updateUsername(newUsername: String) {
        if (userId != "") {
            val data = hashMapOf("username" to newUsername)
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users").document(userId)
                .set(data, SetOptions.merge())
        }
    }
}
```

And my Main composable looks like this:

```
fun Main(mainViewmodel: MainViewModel = viewModel(), navHostController: NavHostController) {
    var fabShape = CircleShape
    val state = rememberScaffoldState()
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val isLoggedIn: Boolean by mainViewmodel.isLoggedIn.observeAsState(true)
    val isLoaded: Boolean by mainViewmodel.isLoaded.observeAsState(false)
    val username: String by mainViewmodel.profile.username.observeAsState("")
    var showUsernameChange: Boolean by remember (username){ mutableStateOf(false)}
    if (!isLoggedIn)
        navHostController.navigate(Screen.Login.route)
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = state,
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = "AppName") },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        if (state.drawerState.isClosed) scope.launch { state.drawerState.open() }
                        else scope.launch { state.drawerState.close() }
                    }) {
                        Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, null)
                    }
                }

            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(cutoutShape = fabShape) {
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    selected = true,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, null) })
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    selected = false,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, null) })
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    selected = false,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Search, null) })
                BottomNavigationItem(
                    selected = false,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Settings, null) })
            }
        },
        drawerShape = RoundedCornerShape(
            topStart = 10.dp,
            topEnd = 10.dp,
            bottomStart = 10.dp,
            bottomEnd = 10.dp,
        ),
        drawerContent = {
            Drawer(username = username, onLogoutClick = {mainViewmodel.logOut()}, onUsernameChangeClick = {
                showUsernameChange = true
                scope.launch { state.drawerState.close() }
            })
        },
        drawerGesturesEnabled = true,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                shape = fabShape,
                content = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, null) })
        }
    ) {
        if (isLoaded) {
            content(mainViewmodel = mainViewmodel)
            val hasUsername: Boolean by remember(username) { mutableStateOf(username.isNotEmpty())}
            if (!hasUsername || showUsernameChange) {
                var cacheUsername: String by remember { mutableStateOf(username) }
                    changeUsername(
                        cacheUsername,
                        onNameChange = { cacheUsername = it },
                        onDismiss = {if(showUsernameChange){
                            showUsernameChange = false
                        } },
                        onDoneClick = {
                            mainViewmodel.updateUsername(cacheUsername)
                        })
                }
        } else {
            loading()
        }

    }
}
```

Finally, my change user name composable looks like this:

```
fun changeUsername(username: String, onNameChange : (String) -> Unit, onDoneClick : () -> Unit, onDismiss: () -> Unit){
    val error : Boolean = username.isNullOrEmpty() || username.length > 64 || username.length < 4
    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() }) {
        Card() {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Update Username", modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp), style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle2)
                TextField(value = username,
                    onValueChange = { onNameChange(it) },
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                    isError = error,
                    placeholder = { Text("Username") })
                TextButton(
                    onClick = { onDoneClick() }, modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .align(Alignment.End),
                    enabled = !error
                ) {
                    Text("Done")
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

***The Problem***
Whenever the user updates the username, we update the firebase database.
Whenever the firebase database is updated we get a new document snapshot.
This results in a crash, with the following signature:

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5120; index=-2
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTableKt.groupSize(SlotTable.kt:2558)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotTableKt.access$groupSize(SlotTable.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SlotReader.groupSize(SlotTable.kt:596)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2215)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2499)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2625)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:406)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:724)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:100)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:437)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$2.invoke(Recomposer.kt:411)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:112)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:43)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:72)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:964)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:721)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Whats going on here? How can we fix it?

Comment: This looks like https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180124293. Looks like a fix has been implemented and will hopefully be out with Beta 2!

Comment: Do you believe its related specifically to the dialog?

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like.

Comment: Confirmed. Removing the dialog, worked. Do you think I should report this as an issue?

Comment: There is another issue with similar code to yours (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181282423), but it was marked as duplicate of the issue I linked previously. Given that the stacktrace is exactly the same, it would be worth verifying if the issue is fixed on the latest Compose snapshot. You can include that by following the instructions on androidx.dev. If that doesn't fix the issue for you, file another issue.